# How to get the event when a picker view stopped scrolling

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad, uipickerview

I need to perform some code when the user stop scrolling the picker, in other way, when the picker stop scrolling. The logic i want to follow is, once the picker stop scrolling, i get the current value and i do some database queries basing on that value.

In the picker view documentation, i don't see a delegate method that can help on such task. Any thoughts? thanx in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

whenever you scroll the picker view, didSelect delegate method call at the end of scroll

```
- (void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)thePickerView didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row inComponent:(NSInteger)component {

NSLog(@"Selected  %i. ",  row);
/// do it here your queries
}
```

try with above example and check your console

Comment: Hi, thanx for the reply, actually `row` is of type integer, so it would be `NSLog(@"Selected  %i. ",  row);`

Comment: actually almost, i needed the value and not the row index, so it was solved like this: `- (void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row inComponent:(NSInteger)component{
    NSInteger selectedRow=[themeList selectedRowInComponent:0];
 NSString *item=[pickerArrayThemesList objectAtIndex:selectedRow];
    NSLog(@"%@",item);
    
}
`

Comment: The solution you give is for retrieving the index of the selected, in my case i need the value itself, so i solved getting the value from the array `pickerArrayThemesList  ` which its elements have been put on the picker. Thanx for your help :)

Comment: hi what's the pickerArrayThemesList?

Comment: It's an NSArray and contains the elements of the picker, so in the `titleForRow` data source method, i used it to identify the elements of the picker.

Answer (score 1):

The delegate class has a method [`pickerView:didSelectRow:inComponent:`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIPickerViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/UIPickerViewDelegate.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UIPickerViewDelegate/pickerView%3adidSelectRow%3ainComponent%3a), that you can use to detect the selected row.